# Haskell - No instance for (Id (HFun a a)) although all instances are defined

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to build a custom category:

```
type Cat i = i -> i -> Type

class Category (h :: Cat i) where
  id :: h a a
  (.) :: h b c -> h a b -> h a c

-------------------------------------------------

data HFun (l :: [Type]) (l' :: [Type]) where
    HFunNil :: HFun '[] '[]
    (:->:) :: (a -> b) -> HFun as bs -> HFun (a ': as) (b ': bs)

class Id x where
    id :: x

instance Id (HFun '[] '[]) where
    id = HFunNil

instance Id (HFun l l) => Id (HFun (a ': l) (a ': l)) where
    id = Pr.id :->: id  

instance Category HFun where
  id = id
```

but this fails to compile with: **No instance for (Id (HFun a a)) arising from a use of ‘id’** :( any help/suggestion is much appreciated

Comment: You covered the cases `a=[]` and `a=(b:l)`. This intuitively covers all cases, but GHC won't accept that, requiring instead an instance `Id (HFun a a)` (or a more general one, `Id (HFun a1 a2)`). I'm not sure about how to fix this.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example that we can test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a dummy `HFunId :: HFun as as` constructor to your type, or add constraints to your category

```hs
type Cat :: Type -> Type
type Cat ob = ob -> ob -> Type

type     Empty :: ob -> Constraint
class    Empty a
instance Empty a

type  Category :: Cat ob -> Constraint
class Category (cat :: Cat ob) where
  type Obj (cat :: Cat ob) :: ob -> Constraint
  type Obj _ = Empty

  id  :: Obj cat a => cat a a
  (.) :: cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c
```

Then you can define a constraint that allows you to pattern match on the spine of a list:

```hs
type Spine :: [k] -> Type
data Spine as where
  Spineless :: Spine '[]
  Spine     :: Spine as -> Spine (a:as)

type  SpineI :: [k] -> Constraint
class SpineI as where
  spine :: Spine as

instance SpineI '[] where
  spine :: Spine '[]
  spine = Spineless

instance SpineI as => SpineI (a:as) where
  spine :: Spine (a:as)
  spine = Spine spine
```

Then you can define `id` for `HFun :: Cat [Type]`:

```hs
instance Category HFun where
  type Obj HFun = SpineI

  id :: SpineI as => HFun as as
  id = go spine where

    go :: forall xs. Spine xs -> HFun xs xs
    go Spineless  = HFunNil
    go (Spine as) = id :->: go as

  (.) :: HFun bs cs -> HFun as bs -> HFun as cs
  (.) = undefined
```